# How can I use multi threading in node js?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, instagram-api

I have a program and I want that program to work for several users, with different passwords. How can I solve this problem with using node js?
I use instagram-private-api and want to login multiple accounts.

Comment: First off, node.js doesn't do multi-threading Javascript (well, it's just starting to in node v10, but that isn't really what you need).  If you're just doing networking, you can have many different requests in flight at the same time because of the asynchronous and non-blocking design of node.js.  That's how node.js scales up to large deployments with only one thread.  If you really need to get multiple CPUs involved, then you would fire up multiple node.js processes and pass different work to each one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the point of node js.  The reason why many other languages use threading (C#, java, c++, etc) is because all the code written is synchronous.  Rather, it executes line by line.  Line 10 doesn't execute until line 9 finishes.  However, this is not to say they don't have asynchronous implementations.  These days there are ways to write asynchronous syntax in those languages, but generally speaking, they're mostly all synchronous.

Enter javascript and the nodejs platform.  95% of it is asynchronous (95% is a total guess and more of a figure of speech, but there are "synchronous" functions... which should be used very rarely and, generally just avoided).  So node uses a "single thread", but operates around something called an event loop.  Not going to go into details about that here, but you can google on what the event loop is and how it works... other folks will explain it better than I can.  Thus, because of that design, and because of the asynchronous nature, you really don't need threading in your nodejs application.

Sounds like you need to just go get your feet wet with node.  Take some tutorials, etc.  It's quite trivial to handle multiple users at once, and no threading is necessary.

Also, if none of that makes sense, then also go read up on "synchronous vs asynchronous".

Answer (score 0):

Node js is a single threaded language but has asynchronous functions. For example if we use a loop in node js then as node js is single threaded then nothing can be executed until that loop finishes but this is not the case. We can use async functions which will run in event loop side by side with the main thread.